# How to load a file in GWT on the client side?

Tags: java, gwt

I'm kind of new to GWT and I'm looking how to make a menu in my client app like File->Open .. that will actualy open an text file and let me edit it in some widget ? Is there a way to load files like that ?

Comment: i removed the app-engine tag, as this sounds like a GWT question, not related to app engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`FileUpload`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FileUpload.html) is a GWT widget that wraps the HTML `<input type='file'>` element. So, just as `<input type='file'>`, it uses the operating system's open/save dialog.

Comment: and if I want the file to be stored locally not uploaded to server ?

Comment: Good question :D One way would be to send it to the server and then retrieve it back via RequestBuilder - but that's just stupid/wasteful. You should post a new question regarding this - I'm sure someone will be able to help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add this functionality by having an upload dialog using a regular file input type and pointing the file-> open button to an event which causes the "browse" button part of that input type to trigger.

Comment: the upload dialog comes with the standard gwt or is it with smart gwt ?